# Bower components root when using gulp connect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, bower, gulp-connect

So my directory structure at its root contains

```
app/
bower_components/
node_modules
..bowercc
gulpfile.js
....etc.....
```

under app are other folders like"

```
/css/
/js/
/assets/
index.html
/view/
```

So my issue is this with a very simple gulp file. My bower components do not load and therefore Angular never attaches. My .bowercc looks like:

```
{
  "directory": "bower_components"
}
```

My gulpfile.js looks like:

//gulp
var gulp = require ('gulp');

//plugins
var connect = require ('gulp-connect');

```
gulp.task('connect', function () {
    connect.server({
        root: [__dirname],
        port: 8888
    });
});
```

I am using the gulp connect plugin and according to what I understand, since my bower_components sits at the root rather than under the '/app' folder, I could simply use [dirname], but that breaks things. If I leave the root option blank, no dependencies load and I get 404's for bootstrap, font-awesome, etc... that I rely on from bower.

Surely some of you understand how to fix this? I do not want to resort to using Require as I just want to make it work the way my structure currently is. What all can I do here?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 9):

Try following

```
connect.server({
    root: ['app'],
    port: 3000,
    livereload: true,
    middleware: function(connect) {
        return [connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('bower_components'))];
    }
});
```